# NetworkOnMainThreadException in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-ndk

I have this exception. How can I do this using Threading concept?

```
public class WebService extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    private final String NAMESPACE ="http://tempuri.org/";//"http://localhost:9583/YP_Android_WebService/YP_Android_WebService.asmx";//
    private final String URL ="http://10.0.2.2:1243/YP_Android_WebService/YP_Android_WebService.asmx?WSDL";

    public boolean checkUser(String _EmailID, String _Password) {

         boolean result = false; 

        final String SOAP_ACTION ="http://tempuri.org/checkUser";//"http://localhost:9583/YP_Android_WebService/YP_Android_WebService.asmx/checkUserLogin";//
        final String METHOD_NAME = "checkUser";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        PropertyInfo propertyInfoEmail = new PropertyInfo();
        propertyInfoEmail.setName("_EmailID");
        propertyInfoEmail.setValue(_EmailID);
        propertyInfoEmail.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(propertyInfoEmail);

        PropertyInfo propertyInfoPassword = new PropertyInfo();
        propertyInfoPassword.setName("_Password");
        propertyInfoPassword.setValue(_Password);
        propertyInfoPassword.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(propertyInfoPassword);

         final SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true; // put this only if the web service is .NET one
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            final HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {


            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            Log.i("myApp", response.toString());
            if(response.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                result = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The Exception is at this point.

> androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); ti throws
>   NetworkonMainThread Exception.

Can any one help me to do this using Thread concept

Comment: Read this: **[Why Ice Cream Sandwich Crashes Your App](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)**

Answer (score 4):

You are not using the `Asynctask` properly. You have unimplemented methods. You have to do all the Network / Database operations in the `doInBackground()` method, and as @Dirk said, UI in the `onPostExecute()` method.

This [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) is also very helpful for you to understand `AsyncTasks` and learn more about `Threads`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting this exception is because you are attempting to perform an expensive operation on the UI thread, which can significantly slow your app down and cause it to force close. You should wrap your code in an `AsyncTask` (or `Thread`) instead.

Read this for more info:

### [Why Ice Cream Sandwich Crashes Your App](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to solve this problem. Do the networking in doInBackground() and the UI modifying in onPostExecute().

Answer (score 0):

You should use Asynctask, but if you do not want to simply add the below code snippet (although not recommended):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) { // disabling strict-mode
                                                    // for newer builds
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
```

Comment: This is a very, very, ***very*** bad solution to the problem. NEVER disable `StrictMode`... it is there for a reason.

Comment: I never said the user should use it, but was simply showing it as a solution should they choose not to heed the caution.

Comment: Upvoted. While it's certainly a very bad idea to use that in production, it's ridiculous to require developers to write a full fledged Asynctask just to test a few hunches/assumptions when debugging stuff.